# CSS Background image crop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm try to use big background image in my site, but when I insert it on the page it's cropped from the top and bottom, may anybody help me? Also I'm use twitter bootstrap.

```
<div id="page1" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="bg">

    </div>
</div>

    body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

    #page1, #page2, #page3, #page4, #page5, #page6, #page7, #page8 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#page1 {
    background: url('Images/Background/1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to take up the entire full screen? Or do you have a live example I can see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want that the background-image isn't cropped?

Then use `background-size: contain;` instead of `background-size: cover;`.

With `background-size: 100% 100%;` your image will be expended (if it is important that the full page have a background).

When IE8 and older is important for you, then you have to use a polyfill. For more information: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Keep in mind, that on small screens, your image will be to big and cost time to load and resize. You can use CSS3 Media Queries (http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20queries) to prevent this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information I see, and if you want it to indefinitely scale to the size of the page, you can use `css3`. Change this:

`background-size: cover;`

to...

`background-size: 100% 100%;`

---

Alternatively, you could just `position: absolute;` a div with a lower `z-index` than your page. For Example...

http://jsfiddle.net/V29P4/

Comment: Feel free to resize the fiddle all you want :-)